# Como alterar oque está escrito em um tkinter.Text em Python?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

Em um `tkinter.Entry`, para alterar oque está escrito eu poderia colocar uma `StringVar` em um textvariable e eu poderia alterar essa `StringVar` há qualquer momento que seria alterado no `tkinter.Entry` também

Mas em um widget `tkinter.Text`?
Tentei usar uma `StringVar` e deu erro.

Meu objetivo era criar um app onde o usuário digita qualquer coisa e quando o botão é pressionando todo aquele texto seria convertido para maiúsculo, o código ficou assim:

```
from tkinter import *


class Teste:
    def __init__( self ):
        self.app = Tk()
        self.app.title( 'Teste' )
        self.app.geometry( '700x700' )
        
        self.string = StringVar()
        
        self.txt = Text( self.app, textvariable=self.string )
        self.txt.pack()
        
        Button( self.app, text="Converter para Maiúsculo", command=self.converteMaiusculo ).pack()
        
        
        self.app.mainloop()
        
    def converteMaiusculo( self ):
        n = self.txt.get( "1.0", END )
        self.string.set( n.upper() )
        
        
myApp = Teste()
```

Eu não sabia que não poderia usar um text ou textvariable em um `tkinter.Text`, mas então como poderia fazer isso?

Answer (score 0):

Neste caso não é muito necessário usar uma StringVar, você pode pegar o conteúdo, armazenar numa string, deletar tudo dentro do Text e inserir com upper

```
def converteMaiusculo( self ):
        n = self.txt.get( "1.0", END )
        self.txt.delete(1.0,END)
        self.txt.insert("insert",n.upper())
```

Mas caso você queira usar StringVar com o seu Text pode ser utilizado o bind KeyRelease pra toda vez que o user digitar qualquer coisa, o bind executar uma função para pegar o texto e setar na StringVar

Exemplo:

```
def salvarStringVar(e): 
    self.string.set(self.txt.get("1.0",END))
    


self.txt.bind('<KeyRelease>',salvarStringVar)
```